# Python: How to type hint tf.keras object in functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, type-hinting

This example function returns a dictionary of keras tensors:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

def create_input_tensors(data: pd.DataFrame) -> Dict[str,tf.keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor]:
   """Turns each dataframe column into a keras tensor and returns them as a dict"""
   tensors = {}
   for name, column in data.items():
      tensors[name] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1, ), name=name, dtype=float32)
   return tensors
```

I do not know how to correctly type hint the return value. Running the code snippet yields the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'engine'
```

Googling this exception did not help. Running `type(tensors['year'])` in the debugger at the end of the function to see what type one of the elements in the return dictionary is (`year` is one of the columns in `data`) yields `<class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>`.

I have issues with this specific function, but also generally when trying to type hint functions that handle any kind of keras object. An answer that is applicable to these similar problems would be much appreciated.

Comment: a type hint for a dict is just this:  `def create_input_tensors(data: pd.DataFrame) -> dict`

Comment: @D.L it's not _just_ that. `dict` only tells you the container type. a `dict[str, str]` is different from a `dict[int, int]`

Comment: that is because of the attribute. does it exist ?  removing the attribute works `def create_input_tensors(data: pd.DataFrame) -> dict[int, int, tf.keras]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works like a charm for me:

```
import typing
from keras.engine.keras_tensor import KerasTensor

def f() -> typing.Dict[str, KerasTensor]:
    return {"a": tf.keras.Input(shape=(1, ),)}

f()
```

Comment: This solves the problem. Yet, like [keras vs. tensorflow.python.keras - which one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893528/keras-vs-tensorflow-python-keras-which-one-to-use) I would prefer not to use keras in my project at all. Going with tensorflow, however, as in `tf.keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor` does not work for me.

Comment: @Viktor `tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor`?

Comment: I used `import tensorflow as tf`and then `tf.keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor`. This should be the same as `tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor`. So @Alberto, yes.

Comment: @Viktor yes it's the same, you're welcome