# How to migrate from keras.engine.[...] to tf.keras.engine?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As discussed in [keras vs. tensorflow.python.keras - which one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893528/keras-vs-tensorflow-python-keras-which-one-to-use) I generally do not want to include keras in my machine learning project. Yet in the following code example using keras works and tf.keras does not:

```
>>>import keras
>>>print(keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor)
```

```
<class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>
```

and

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
>>>print(tf.keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\reifv\root\Heidelberg Master\Netflix_AI_codes\working env - Copy\Netflix_AI\main copy.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(tf.keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor)
  File "C:\Users\reifv\root\Heidelberg Master\Netflix_AI_codes\working env - Copy\Netflix_AI\venvnf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 59, in __getattr__
    return getattr(module, item)
AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'engine'
```

This is one example of tf.keras not working, but I encountered this issue several times along my project. Therefore, a general solution would be much appreciated, too.

Comment: What is your need to use keras.engine? What exactly are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy I use it for type hinting. Two examples are `keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor` and `keras.engine.functional.Functional`.

Comment: Well that will not work because the engine module does not exist in latest keras versions.